# Matebook D15 2021 - no sound on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, audio, pulseaudio, alsamixer

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Huawei Matebook D15 2021 (i3-10gen) and I haven't got any sound. In devices I can only see "Dummy Output". Is there any drivers for audio?
I've read on the Internet that someone installed Kernel 5.18.6 and it started working but in my case there is no difference. Any ideas?